# Strange margin/padding in Firefox that doesn't occur in other browsers

Tags: css, firefox

We've been working on a new website and there is some mystery padding/margin occurring just in Firefox 6 that doesn't appear in any other browser (including IE).

What it should look like:

[image: What it should look like]

What Firefox displays:

[image: What Firefox displays]

The additional margin/padding is appearing just above the Blackboard + Portal buttons.

Playing with Firebug it's something to do with the float:left on ul.springboard li.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: Would you mind to post any HTML + CSS code? Raw description is not very helpful.

Comment: We need code, yet the problem might be caused by white-space.

Comment: @Ventus and c69: The [website in question](http://gateway.lncn.eu/) seems to be publicly accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried removing the clearfix class and adding the following rules to `ul.springboard`:

```
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
```

That removed the space in Firefox, but I'm not sure how it will impact other `ul` elements that use `.springboard` class.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you don't actually have styles set up for `.clearfix` yet. The following CSS additions should sort you out.

```
/* Micro-clearfix, via goo.gl/QjJD9 */
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content:""; display:table; }
.clearfix:after { clear:both; }
/* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
.clearfix { zoom:1; }
```

Comment: Thanks but line 288 of http://c94471.r71.cf3.rackcdn.com/cwd.css has styling for .clearfix